# Obtener el ultimo elemento de un array con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

¿saben como puedo obtener el ultimo elemento almacenado en un array con jquery? He creado una petición que me devuelve un array de id's. Me gustaria poder almacenar el ultimo valor del array para después manejarlo.

¿Saben como puedo hacerlo?

```
            <script>
            function addproduct(id){
                $.ajax({
                url:'{{ path('mycart') }}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                "idproduct": id
            },
            async: true,
            success:function (idproduct) { //Devuelve un array
                console.log(idproduct);

            
                $( '#addproduct' + /*aqui iria el ultimo id */ ).prop('value', 'Añadido al carrito');
                $( '#addproduct' + /*aqui iria el ultimo id */ ).css('background-color', "#d4edda").css('color', '#155724').css('border-color', '#c3e6cb');
            }
            });
            };

        </script>
```

**ACTUALIZACION**
He utilizado `const lastid = idproduct[idproduct.length - 1];`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al pulsar en el primer producto, todo va bien. El problema viene al presionar en el segundo. No se por qué pero me aparece ese extraño corchete que impide que se ejecute bien.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas jQuery para eso, simplemente **accede al último indice** y almacenas el id en otra variable. **El último indice es la longitud - 1(n -1)**. Si idproduct es un JSON primero se tiene que convertir.

```
// esta linea es opcional
idproduct = JSON.parse(idproduct);

let ultimo_id = idproduct[idproduct.length - 1];
$( '#addproduct' + ultimo_id).prop('value', 'Añadido al carrito');
$( '#addproduct' + ultimo_id).css('background-color', "#d4edda").css('color', '#155724').css('border-color', '#c3e6cb');
```

Comment: Si pongo esa linea, me sale el error **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #addproduct]** Creo que de alguna manera esta capturando el corchete en vez de el valor

Comment: Puedes colocar como imagen qué es lo que muestra esta linea console.log(idproduct);

Comment: Hecho, ya esta actualizado

Comment: Prueba ahora, puse JSON.parse

Comment: Ahora si, muchisimas gracias!! Que diferencia hay entre JSON.parse y idproduct.length - 1??

Comment: Los dos son totalmente diferentes, lo que ocurre es que el resultado de la petición AJAX está devolviendo un string JSON como este "["1", "2", "2"]". Lo que se necesita para manipular, es convertir ese JSON en Array.